# Can we choose any arbitrary vector to “shrink” towards for the James-Stein Estimator?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, james-stein-estimator

My understanding of the James-Stein estimator is that the choice of the origin as the point to shrink towards is more for neatness than anything else, and that the estimator still dominates MLE for other arbitrary choices.

I’m having trouble reconciling this with the fact that the classical examples of the JS estimator seem to rely on a very non-arbitrary choice - for example in the famous baseball batting average case, the overall mean hit rate is chosen. If we’d chosen an arbitrarily high value then the JS estimator would have performed terribly.

In general I’m not quite getting how simultaneously

1. We can pick any point to be our “starting guess” for the parameter and the estimator will outperform (I understand that the amount of outperformance is dependent on the distance to the “true mean” vector) and
2. The shrinkage away from the starting guess is weaker the further away it is from the sampled value

Comment: This is why people become Bayesian

Comment: I’m all for being Bayesian when we have some decent idea for a prior over the parameter space, but I thought JS is interesting precisely because you can outperform MLE without needing any prior